# Linear equation with additive noise

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The following is an excerpt from Mikosch's *Elementary Stochastic Calculus*:

> [image]

I'm trying to understand the calculation in the red box where the version of Ito's lemma mentioned is as follows:

> [image]
>   [image]

---

**Question**:
How is (2.30) used in the red box?

---

I tried to apply (2.30) directly by using $f(t,x)=y(t)x$ and
$$
A_s^{(1)}=c_1(s)X_s+c_2(s),\quad A_s^{(2)}=\sigma_2(s). 
$$
But I ended up with something very different from the desired formula in the red box. (For instance, in my calculation, the term $c_1'(t)$ pops up. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the desired formula due to wrong calculation of the partial derivatives. For $f(t,x)=y(t)x,$ one should have
$$
f_1(t,x)=y'(t)x=-c_1(t)y(t)x\\
f_2(t,x)=y(t)\\
f_{22}(t,x)=0
$$
A direct substitution to (2.30) would then solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using a multivariate Ito formula, which in this context is also known as stochastic integration by parts
$$d(XZ) = XdZ+ZdX+d[X,Z].$$
In your case $Z\equiv y$ and $dZ\equiv dy = -c_1 y dt$ so the quadratic covariation part is zero. After substituting for $dX$ and simplifying you will end up with 
$$ d(Xy)=-c_1 Xy dt + y dX = y(c_2 dt +\sigma_2 dB).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would (2.30) fit in your argument? Or do you think the author uses the wrong version of Ito formula?

Comment: That's what I tried as I mentioned in the last paragraph. But I got something unexpected. I'm still slowly reading your answer. I might come back later.